# How do I turn off line highlighting due to exception in Netbeans 8.0?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8

In Netbeans 8.0, when an exception is thrown and I click on the link for it in the console, Netbeans takes me to the exact line for the exception and highlights it like so:

[image: Line highlighting due to exception]

I like this feature, but I cannot find a way to get rid of the highlighting (and the red [x]) once I am done fixing the particular issue. I've tried closing and reopening the file and right-clicking the red [x] (there are no relevant options in the context-menu). The only way that I've found to get rid of it is to shutdown Netbeans and restart. How can I turn off line highlighting that occurs due to exceptions? Please note that I do not want to turn off the feature completely, I just want to be able to turn off the highlighting for a particular line once I have dealt with the issue.

**Edit:** It may be relevant to mention that my code is running on a server. When I shutdown the server the highlighting goes away. However I still would rather turn off the highlighting manually if possible so that I do not have to shutdown the server.

Answer (score 4):

You can get rid of the error highlighting by right clicking the same console with the link, and clicking `Clear`, or just click `ctrl+L`.

It's not ideal since it gets rid of the log information. But it's the way I've found to get rid of the error highlighting short of what you suggested.